# How do I exclude/include certain component.spec.ts files from running in my Jenkins build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jenkins

I am trying to get my spec.ts files into sonarqube to get code coverage . But my Jenkins build is failing because of some spec.ts files. Is there any way to exclude these spec.ts files and only include certain files in the Jenkins build given that I cannot delete the spec.ts files from the angular package.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways:

1. Change the glob patterns in your `tsconfig.spec.json`
2. To exclude a `describe block` change it to `xdescribe`
3. To exclude a specific test `it` change it to `xit`

Reading a little bit more on Jasmine will help.
https://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html

Comment: I have tried 2 and 3 but that doesn't work. It works for my local.. but that doesn't work for the Jenkins build.. despite doing xdescribe and xit., Jenkins is still running the file and the test cases. Yet to try 1.